# Why the zoom level of my .net chart component is set to maximum on load

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I've an issue with the .Net chart component.
When my form loads, I manually set the zoom level of the chart (it's a bar chart)
but the zoom level is set very hight.

this bug occurs randomly.

when I run the code in debug, all values are correctly set, but the chart is not correctly displayed.

I set the zoom with this code

```
MonitoringChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, ItemToDisplay);
```

in debug, the ItemToDisplay is set to 20, but I only see the first bar of the chart, zoomed at the maximum.

any idea how to solve this?

thanks

Comment: You probably have `AutoScaling` on.

Comment: Autoscaling? where can I find this property? (chart area, axi)